# whats wrong with my XML for document ranking?

Tags: asp.net, xml, information-retrieval

I wrote a program in C# to calculate TF-IDF to rank documents.

I used the following XML to store the word frequencies within documents. I was criticised heavily for using this structure. Even though I use the text of the word within the Tag, as per me its efficient and consumes less space. Also, I can make a search using XDocument pretty easily since its a nice tree structure. Can you help me understand why was I criticised heavily?

Criticism: How can you add information within meta-data? (For me its innovative).

```
<word>
   <siddhartha>
      <doc1> 4 </doc4>
      <doc2> 5 </doc2>

   <insipration>
      <doc1> 4 </doc1>
      <doc6> 5 </doc6>

   ....
</word>
```

I was suggested something like this:

```
   <word>
   <text> siddhartha </text>
   <doc1> 4 </doc1>
   <text> inspiration </text>
   <doc1> 4 </doc1>
   ...
   </word>
```

Comment: It would help for you to air said criticisms.

Comment: "I wrote a program in C# to calculate TF-IDF to rank documents." What is "TF-IDF" ?

Comment: @Kirk How can you insert information within meta-data!

Comment: @Jeff Algorithm to rank documents based on a keyword search. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf*idf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your structure, with word name as node, will be hard to parse with generic parsers. There is no defined structure: you need to read the whole document to know it.

I may have done something like this (I tried to stay closed to your idea):

```
<words>
   <word id="siddhartha">
      <freq id="doc1"> 4 </freq>
      <freq id="doc2"> 5 </freq>
   </word>
   ....
</words>
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestioin. To search a frequency I use: perdoc.Root.Element("siddhartha").Element("doc1").value. How would this be replaced using your structure?

Comment: Ouch... I don't parse XML everyday :) but it should be very easy, you just need to select word node by its ID attribute, then fetch the child same way.  May be you have already such methods in your API.

Comment: IEnumerable<XElement> users =
        (from el in XMLDoc.root.Elements("Word")
         where (string)el.Attribute("id") == "siddhartha"
         select el); for a start.